# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Reference Cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, excel, reference

I am having troubles adding the excel reference to my project. I have already installed Primary Interop Assemblies.

The project is detecting the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly reference correctly but the excel reference still cannot be found.

When I try to manually add the reference, I right click the project, add reference, navigate to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel file and try to add it manually. Once i select the reference I then make sure the reference is checked, then hit ok. Nothing happens, it fails to actually add the reference path to the project.

Using VS2012 Ultimate.

Any suggestions on what I can do to get the project to see the excel reference?

Comment: Have a read of the top answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll

Comment: I have already tried this. I.e. trying to manually add the reference. It still does not recognize the .Excel reference. The .Word reference is recognized correctly.

Comment: When you manually try to add it, is it already listed in the extensions as shown in Paul's link?  I know that 2012 is probably different, but when I did this in 2010 I had to use the COM reference as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9e83756-4ae2-4ed4-b154-1537f3bb3a22/cant-find-microsoftofficeinteropexceldll?forum=netfxsetup.

Comment: It is not already listed like it is in Paul's link, I have to manually click browse and navigate to the folder that contains the .Excel reference.
The directions in your link worked when adding the reference. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, added as answer.

Comment: Run this command: Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As described in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9e83756-4ae2-4ed4-b154-1537f3bb3a22/cant-find-microsoftofficeinteropexceldll?forum=netfxsetup

- On the Project menu, click "Add Reference."
- On the COM tab, click Microsoft Excel Object Library, and then click Select. In Visual Studio 2012, locate Microsoft Excel 14.0 (or other version) Object Library on the COM tab.
- Click OK in the Add References dialog box to accept your selections. If you are prompted to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click “Yes”.

Comment: Same issue with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. I just needed to add `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` from the COM tab.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't have excel installed, run this command in the nuget-packet-manager-console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Answer (score 9):

I installed Microsoft office PIAs, but I had the same problem, cannot find microsoft.office.interop.excel dll, I also I installed Visual Studio 2010 Tools for the Office System 4.0 Runtime Service Pack 1 but still the problem persist.

Finally I resolve the problem with an add of Office / SharePoint development package to my Visual Studio 2017 installation:

Go to Tools > Get Tools and Features ..

And then check Office / sharepoint development and modify your installation.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much! I was fighting this problem for days and the only answer that worked for me had 0 votes....

Answer (score 1):

I installed MS Office 13 and from then on I started getting this error in VS 2012 project. 
I tried adding the MS Office lib via COM control but that didnt work. 
Finally I had to add this library references from the "Extensions" section (not not under COM); had to select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, version 15.0.0.0. That fixed the error.

Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to move a project to my dev machine from a consultant.

My working machine reference pointed to Microsoft.Office.Interop
My non-working machine wanted "Excel" to come from DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet which was also in the project.

I needed to
Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console   and type "Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

*then* I needed to "Add Reference" as described above.

Movin to my co-worker's machine we had to do these two steps *and* close and open the project to get it all to take.