# VB.NET Missing Reference (Microsoft.Office.Interop) after MS Office Recovery

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office

Just before I got a problem with excel and I recovered MS Office with online option. After that my excel works well, but my project in Visual Basic VB.NET lost excel reference(Microsoft.Office.Interop). I recovered already Visual Studio, but it still loses reference. I use Office Home & Student 2019 and Visual Studio 2019. Please, help me to fix it.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "loses reference"? Do you mean that it's missing and can't be re-added? Or that it randomly disappears after being added? More explicit info please.

Comment: As you can see the picture, then you can see that I chceked already Office 16.0 that means Office 2019. But why tell the VS that the Microsoft.Office.Interop is unnecessary? Before I recovered MS Office, everything worked well. Do you have any experience or idea to fix it?

Comment: Refer my answer regarding the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` extension library. What you're adding here is an old COM library. You're not using VBA, are you? You've said `VB.NET` in your question title.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment! I searched in extension library, but the all of type "Microsoft.Office.---" doesn't exist...

Comment: I think that I found the solution. I googled it and I just add it that is in here "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` extension library?

[image]

Further to your comments, if that reference isn't available/visible, check this SO question: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Reference Cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543279/microsoft-office-interop-excel-reference-cannot-be-found).

Personally, out of the answers there, I'd try the NuGet option first:

[image]

Comment: Than you for your answer, I searched it in the extensions, but I have no "Microsfot.Office.---"...

Comment: I think that I found the solution. I googled it and I just add it that is in here "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". Is that right?