# Getting a "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" error

Tags: c#

I have been trying to run these two lines within my code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

For some reason I keep on getting this error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to configure the right assembly to Visual Studios 2013 to make these lines work? They worked well in Visual Studios 2010. Your help could be greatly appreciated... Thanks

Comment: They work in vs 2010 because you have referenced the interop dll's in that project.  Do you have the dll's listed in the references section of your project in 2013?

Comment: See if this helps: _[How to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll)_

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.. I was unaware of this simple fix since I am new to the development world of microsoft

Answer (score 5):

1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click your project's name and then click
   `Add Reference`. The Add Reference dialog box appears.
2. On the Assemblies page, select `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in the
   Component Name list
3. If you do not see the assemblies, you may need to ensure they are
   installed and displayed `Click OK`.

Comment: I believed that fixed my problem. Thanks!