# Insert Excel Rows/Columns with ExcelDNA or NetOffice

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, netoffice

I am using [ExcelDNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/) to set and get cell values.  I can get and set cell values

```
var ref = ExcelReference(2, 2);
var val = ref.GetValue();
ref.SetValue(42);
```

is there a way to insert an entire row or column by moving entries to the right or down?  I want the same behavior as when the user right clicks the column and all the entries are shifted to the right.  Solution can use NetOffice if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the COM object model for this, and the code will be similar to VBA for the same task.

You get hold of the root `Application` object with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`. The resulting object will be of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` and can be used to select the row of column, then call `app.Selection.Insert()` to insert the new row or column.

It should also be possible using the C API, but that is unlikely to be easier or faster.

Comment: ExcelDnaUtil.Application returns an instance of System.__ComObject.  Which version of ExcelDna are you on?

Comment: Yes - it's a COM object that is really the Excel Application object. If you reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel you can cast it to Application.

Comment: I had to add an extra dll reference to get this working.  Instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that NetOffice does not support the `EntireRow` and `EntireColumn` methods of the Range object, which would be useful for inserting or deleting full rows. As a workaround, one can replace this for rows by addressing full rows by `Range(rowNoStart + ":" + rowNoEnd)`.

For columns, one can write `Range(GetExcelColumnName(colStart) + ":" + GetExcelColumnName(colEnd))`, where `GetExcelColumnName` is a function from [this former SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa).

Comment: I was wondering about the differences between NetOffice and Excel-DNA, in case you know about this. I can open a question if you want me to. Thanks much!

Comment: @NoChance: ExcelDNA and NetOffice fulfill different purposes, and they are orthogonal to each other, so the question about their differences makes no sense. NetOffice is a capsule around the COM object model of main MS Office programs, which allows writing programs which don't bind themselves to a specific Excel or Word version. So you could ask which parts of the full COM object model are still not supported by NetOffice, that would be a sensible question.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out, I have only knew about the products recently and did not have a chance to go deep. Thank you for your answer.