# How to read .xls in a webpage running in IIS7?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7, xls, excel.application

I am trying to read as web-page content an excel file. I thought going through vbscript in classic ASP.

But ...The code is taking so long to open and when it works, the page comes in blank! That should I do please?

```
<%

Dim xls  
response.ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.application")

xls.Visible = False

xls.Workbooks.Open("R:\wb\excel\Middleware.xls") 

%>
```

And I tried also:

```
<% 

Set opena = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
opena.Application.Workbooks.Open "R:\wb\excel\Content.xls"

%>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the JET database driver? -  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195951

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll would appear to be a similar question.

Comment: I rather to instance the excel file than parse the excel content by using ADO

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to use Office Automation in a server-side. You might want to look at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

I would instead strongly recommend that you use to the new formats (.xlsx) and instead use OpenXML on the server which will be a lot easier/safer/scalable to use.

If you are stuck with .xls then another option is use the old XML format, and I actually wrote a library to generate Excel XML files that you could try if you wanted: http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/

but bottomline I would definitely stay away from Office automation as you are using above, and instead use other libraries that generate the binary formats (either XLS or OpenXML even better if you can use newer version of Office).