# How to add reference Excel in project C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

How to add reference to project that after use:

```
using ExcelObj = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I tried to find this in library list everywhere, but have not found.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll)

Comment: I use 2015 VS, aand tried these solutions

Comment: Did you install the [Microsoft Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not a .Net assembly it should be in the COM->Type Libraries->Microsoft Excel ## Object Library