# c# read specific columns from excel file

Tags: c#, excel

i have a tables like this

[image]

and i added checkboxs elements to form like this

[image]

i want to add the checkbox element text to datagridview then read the checked columns from excel file

if Date, Time, Price are checked datagridview will be like this

[image]

then get full Date column from excel file and add it to Date column in datagrid

my code to add checked boxes text as a columns in datagridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (Control checkbox in pnl.Controls)
        if (checkbox.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) checkbox).Checked)
        {
            string txt = ((CheckBox)checkbox).Text;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(txt, typeof(object)));
        }
datagrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: its not clear...are you working on excel file ?  so if not i suggest you to put off the tag excel..so  another suggestion is to show a minimal example what you have done..helpers could use your program and add the solution code

Comment: Make columns in DGV visible = false : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-hide-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Frenchy yes, i`m working on excel file i wanna create a c# program to read all file columns and rows then add what i need in datagridview

Comment: @jdweng i will try but if u can send to me good code for import excel to datagrib i`m pleasure for this ♥

Comment: All you need to do to display a DataTable to a DataGridview is following : datagridview1.DataSource = dt.

Comment: @DoneNothing, ok so need to read your code because there lot of ways to read excel file

Comment: can you give me the best fastest way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps which are needed before being able to grab data from an Excel file. So without your code, I don't know how much of this you have done. But here is the full explanation.

**First**
You have to add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll (this assumes you aren't using epplus or another Nuget package). This link describes how to do this: [How to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll)

**Second**
Include this library in whichever source file it is needed, and initialize an excel application (you'll also want InteropServices included):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Global excel app object to be used anywhere
public Application ExcelApp;

// Intitializes an excel application by looking for an active one,
// and creating a new one if none are active
public void InitExcelApp()
{
   try
   {
      ExcelApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
   }
   catch(COMException ex)
   {
      ExcelApp = new Application
      {
         Visible = true
      };
   }
}
```

**Third**
You must initialize a workbook object. Here is how I do it, but my solution assumes you know the path to the desired Excel workbook:

```
Workbook myWorkbook = null;

// Checks open workbooks first
// Note that the path must be windows style. Ex: "C:\\Desktop\\myWorkbook.xlsx"
foreach (Workbook openWorkbook in ExcelApp.Workbooks)
{
   if (openWorkbook.FullName == "<path to workbook>")
   {
      myWorkbook = openWorkbook;
   }
}

// If no open workbooks were found at the known path, try opening one 
if(myWorkbook is null)
{
   myWorkbook = Excelapp.Workbooks.Open("<path to workbook>", Editable: true);
}
```

**Fourth**
Get the data you want. There are several ways to do this, and mine might not be the most efficient, but it works. In the code below I have included parameter names to hopefully make it more understandable.

```
// Gets the names of the checked items from the DataTable with columns you already added
// You could get these names from your checkboxes' names if you preferred
List<string> checkItems = new List<string>();
foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
   checkItems.Add(column.ColumnName);
}

// This dictionary holds info helpful for getting the correct data from excel:
// Key: a string containing the name of the column header, i.e. Date, Time, Price, etc.
// Value: an integer containing the number of that column in excel
Dictionary<string, int> excelColumnsInfo = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int columnNum = 1; columnNum <= myWorkbook.UsedRange.Columns.Count; columnNum++)
{
   string columnHeader = myWorkbook.Cells[RowIndex: 1, ColumnIndex: columnNum].Value2.ToString();

   if (checkedItems.Contains(columnHeader))
   {
      excelColumnsInfo.add(columnHeader, columnNum);
   }
}

// Populates the data table with the data you need
// Start at row 2 to ignore the excel sheet's column headers
for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= myWorkbook.UsedRange.Rows.Count; rowNum++)
{
   System.data.dataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> columnInfo in excelColumnsInfo)
   {
      newRow[columnName: columnInfo.Key] = myWorkbook.Cells[RowIndex: rowNum, ColumnIndex: columnInfo.Value].Value2.ToString();
   }

   dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```