# TextRange2 class not registered

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft.office.interop.excel

I had Excel 2010 and Office 365 installed at the same time on my computer. I uninstalled the 365 version due to other issues and now my code crashes when accessing the TextRange2 class. Specifically in the line of code

```
chart.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12;
```

It tells me that the TextRange2 class is not registered. I don't understand anything because if I record a macro with Excel 2010 doing exactly the same, i.e. changing the font size of the legend of a chart, the code it generates is exactly the same.

What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it says `TextRange2`- I would suppose it is `TextFrame2` which might not be availabel in Excel 2010

Comment: Macro generated in Excel 2010 right now:

Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Size = 14
    End With
End Sub

Comment: @PinTxO - But the code generated in Excel 2010 refers to `TextRange` not `TextRange2`. Can you post the exact wording of the error please

Comment: The exact wording of the error is:

Library not registered (HRESULT exception: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

StackTrace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.TextFrame2.get_TextRange()

Comment: Maybe repairing your Office 2010 installation might help.

Comment: I don't have Office 2010 installed. I only have Excel 2010 installed and I reinstalled it yesterday. Anyway, if I'm not mistaken, if I have referenced in my Visual Studio 2017 project, the Interop.Excel.dll and Office.dll files of the VSTO that you install as optional with Visual Studio, it should be enough.

Comment: Something is happening with the Microsoft.Office.Core namespace because I get the same error when accessing the TextColumn2 class. Does anyone know how I can register the dll manually?

Comment: What's happening when/if you try the same code line **in VBA**?

Comment: @FaneDuru No errors

Comment: So, it looks not being a matter of Office/Excel installation. It would be good to see what dll did you reference in your VS Project. To not be the one of the deleted version... I would suggest you to remove it from the project and then reference it from the correct place. It probably will be the single suggested one...

Comment: @FaneDuru I have done this and nothing. The two dll's I am referencing are Office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, both from the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14

I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Try opening a commander window, paste this line `dir /s microsoft.office.interop.excel.*` and run it. But, even if it is there where you referenced it, it is possible that VS installed the version you have uninstalled it. If so, you can try using the NuGet package manager. I remember I could see an old thread showing how to use it...  OK, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll) to inspire...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256084/discussion-between-pintxo-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0):

I've already managed to fix it :-)

I had to delete the 2.8 or 2.9 folder (I don't remember which one I had and it was empty) from the registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52} and leave only the 2.5 folder which is the correct version of Office 2010.

You can see that the 365 uninstaller doesn't properly clean everything it creates when you install it and leaves rubbish that affects previous versions :-@

Link (in Spanish) where I found the solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/msoffice/forum/all/falta-una-referencia-al-archivo-msodll/4a1589dc-a689-4b34-a8eb-0a5ed1737cf9

@FaneDuru Thank you very much :-)